# Extract patterns from tsv table listed in the separate text file and add first 5 cells from the corresponding row

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to extract some specific entries from a large tsv table using a list. I also need corresponding data in the first 5 columns.

listfile.txt

entry123
entry532
entry685
entry555

...etc...

table.tsv

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10 | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | entry787 | val7 | val7 | val7 | val7 | etc... |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | entry532 | val7 | val7 | val7 | etc... |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | entry685 | val7 | val7 | val7 | etc... |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | entry999 | val7 | val7 | val7 | val7 | etc... |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | entry123 | val7 | val7 | etc... |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | val7 | val7 | entry555 | etc... |
| etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... |

output

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entry123 | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 |
| entry532 | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 |
| entry685 | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 |
| entry555 | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 |

I tried this combination but does not work.

`grep -o -F -f listfile.txt table.tsv | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5}' > output`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When asking questions on text processing, please include your examples in "raw" format with "code" formatting, so that contributors can copy-and-paste the examples into their machins for testing (I know that representing tabs is not possible that way, but if you describe the file as tab-separated, contributors will still now what to do ;) ). I would also recommend giving each cell a unique value (such as `val12` for column 2 in line 1) because that can remove ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a tab-separated file that looks like this, with no whitespace in any field:

```
$ cat file
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8    col9    col10   etc...
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    entry123    val7    val7    val7    val7    etc...
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    entry532    val7    val7    val7    etc...
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    entry685    val7    val7    val7    etc...
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    entry999    val7    val7    val7    val7    etc...
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7    val7    val7    entry555    etc...
```

And a listfile that looks like this:

```
$ cat listfile 
entry123
entry532
entry685
entry555
```

You can do what you want with a combination of `grep` and `cut`:

```
$ grep -wf listfile -e 'col1' file | cut -f1-6
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    entry123
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6
```

First, `grep -wf listfile -e 'col1' file` will print all lines that contain one of the words of `listfile` *as a separate word*, so as long as you don't have whitespace in your fields, that means as a separate field. It will also print the header because it is the only line matching `col1` as a separate word. *You will need to use a different word for your real data, pick something that is only ever found in the header*.

Next, this is passed to `cut -f1-6` which keeps only the first 6 fields.